# How to access same file in different location

Tags: php, html

Let me explain my need with simple example.

I have folder called "Website" Inside that some sub folders and files.

Website(Main-Folder)

pages(sub-folder)
(files)
page1.php
page2.php

target_page(sub-folder)
(file)
target.php

menu(sub-folder)
(file)
menu.php

index.php (this file is in main folder)

This is my sample folder view, I just included menu.php(navigation menu with links)file in my both pages and index.php file.

In menu.php i have a nav link to target.php page

So, to

access target.php file in
index page mean i have to use Target

```html
<a href="target_page/target.php">Target</a>
```

access target.php file inside
the pages folder mean i have to use

```html
<a href="../target_page/target.php">Target</a>
```

Is there any short way to access that target page, because I don't like to create multiple menu.php file and set the different location for same file.

Sorry for bad English, Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[UPDATED]
The best alternative is to define your root path once and for all !

---

We use another file that we could call whenever we need the PATH. Like for example in settings.php that we save near index.php:

```
define('My_ROOT' , 'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/');
```

Then whenever needed, we require that file and so we could write links like follwing :

```
<a href="<?php echo My_ROOT;?>target_page/target.php">Target</a>
```

P.S: *Please notice that in my first Answer I used the file path and that could be used for relative inclusion not Frontend links !*

Answer (score 0):

Just put your href starting with "/" :

```
<a href="/target_page/target.php">link</a>
```